# Getting undefined directly after logging object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code...

```
var tagMap = {};
console.log("Data" + data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
for(var item in data.results){
  tagMap[item.path.key] = item.value.name;
}
```

But it outputs...

```
Data[object Object]
{ "count":1,
  "total_count":1,
  "results":[
    {"path": {"collection":"ProcessedReports","key":"20140225.DIF","ref":"4802caab51897eae"},"value":  {"name":"20140225.DIF"},"score":1}
  ]
}
undefined

project/routes/index.js:73
for(var item in data.results){
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
```

I am confused, how is it getting set back to null?

**Update**

Thanks to a comment I noticed the log was actually the following...

```
Data[object Object]
{"count":1,"total_count":1,"results":[{"path":{"collection":"ProcessedReports","key":"20140225.DIF","ref":"4802caab51897eae"},"value":{"name":"20140225.DIF"},"score":1}]}
Dataundefined  
undefined
```

this leads me to believe the method is getting called 2x I will try to add more code asap.

Full route (expressjs) using orchestrate.io, still can't find the dual call. Only 1 call to getloadedfiles I can find so far in the source.

```
exports.getloadedfiles = function(req, res, next){
  miao.search({
    collection: 'ProcessedReports',
    query: '*'
  },
  function (err, data) {
    var tagMap = {};
    console.log("Data" + data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    for(var item in data.results){
      tagMap[item.path.key] = item.value.name;
    }
    req.processed = tagMap;
    return next();
  });
}
```

With the grep of my project...

```
grep -r getloadedfiles ./
  .//app.js:app.get('/files/list', routes.getloadedfiles, routes.getfiles, routes.renderfiles);
  .//routes/index.js:exports.getloadedfiles = function(req, res, next){
```

Comment: What do you get when you log `data` to console directly …?

Comment: Updated with info says it is in fact an object

Comment: Your code above only have two log statements, but you're showing us an output with three logging lines. Are you sure you're showing us the right code?

Comment: Sure let me go back and find it.

Comment: Whatever function that code is in is called twice, the last time without a `data` variable.

Comment: like ive said before `console.dir` will give you a better understanding when debugging an object

Comment: In a callback like that, the first line should generally be `if (err !== null) { handle error; return; }`

Comment: Let me know where you would like me to replace the console.dir and I will. Would you like all of them? Just the object one?

Comment: Try it like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/9GxHd/4/

Comment: Seems to have worked thank you I guess you were right about the iteration. I swear I thought I did it that way before.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should probably be

```
for(var item in data.results){
  tagMap[ data.results[item].path.key ] = data.results[item].value.name;
}
```

accessing the objects values with the key passed in the loop, otherwise you're doing

```
0.path.key
```

as in trying to access properties on the string that is the key, which won't work

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9GxHd/1/)

Another thing, `data.results` is an array, and should be iterated with

```
for (var i=0; i<data.results.length; i++) { ...
```

And then you'd end up with

```
for (var i=0; i<data.results.length; i++) {
    tagMap[data.results[i].path.key] = data.results[i].value.name;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9GxHd/2/)

Comment: This first part looks completely wrong to me. Why not just use the object from the for loop? Isn't that the whole idea behind iterating as I am? As for the second I will have to go back through code but I am pretty sure I have done it the other way before and I have no need for the ordinal location. Sorry man I appreciate the help but I gotta agree with the thumbs down. This doesn't add anything.

Comment: @Jackie - That's because clearly you're not getting it, you have an array, and `item.path` is the same as `0.path`, which is undefined, see this -> http://jsfiddle.net/9GxHd/3/

Comment: And you're not trying to access the object, but the key, it's `for (var key in object)`, and you're treating the key as an object, failure!

Comment: I don't think you are looking at the error. The error is because data is undefined not because of my for logic. I may just not be following you.

Comment: That's right, as I commented on the question, your code runs twice, the last time data is undefined, but my answer still stands, you're iterating over the array completely wrong, and once you've fixed the other issue, you'll realize it.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now my vote is locked but I will at least take away my down vote. Just edit something small.